# Установка joomla

Tags: установка, joomla

Доброго времени суток! Возник вопрос: как в `joomla` реализовано, что если есть папка `installation`, то первой открывается она? в `index.php` перенаправлений я не заметил.

Comment: `print_r(debug_backtrace())` в каком нить файле инсталлера напишите и узнаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.php` подгружает ещё не один файл. В не самой новой Joomla 2.5, например, подгружается `includes/framework.php`, содержащий что-то типа:

```
if (file_exists(JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php')) {
    header('Location: '.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0,
        strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')).'installation/index.php');
    exit();
} else {
    ...
```